# Insert images as part of a QR code?

Tags: google-visualization, qr-code

I'd like to be able to generate custom QR codes that include image/logo designs as part of the actual QR code. Something like detailed here: http://mashable.com/2011/07/23/creative-qr-codes/

Where can I find guidelines on how I can manipulate the QR code that's generated for, say a URL, and still leave it 100% readable/scannable?

Steps of what I'd like to be able to do:

1. Generate QR Code for something, like a web address. (Already doing this with google charts)
2. Insert an graphic/image into the code itself, like a logo.
3. Scan it, and get the URL from step 1.

Comment: If someone could clarify how this is not a real question, I'd appreciate it. I'm genuinely interested in customizing QR codes, and since they are generated/read using applications, it seems appropriate for stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules for what distortion will cause a scanner to fail. While the code itself is standardized, there are no standards for the algorithms that detect a code from an image, including handling real life distortion like perspective and lighting. Different hardware and software perform differently.

The image at the bottom of http://www.swetake.com/qr/qr1_en.html shows some of the "special" areas of code. It's best to leave those areas, all the black, white, and cyan areas, alone. There are additional reserved areas in all but the smallest codes. These show up first in the the lower right quadrant of the code but get repeated multiple times as the code gets larger. Those should also be left intact, particularly for smaller codes.

Changes to the remaining area can generally be corrected if sufficient error encoding is used when the code is created but, again, a lot depends on capture conditions. An unchanged code will always have the highest probability of decoding.